# Swift - How to create an instance of an object whose variables are data from Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, ios8

On my Xcode project I have a class named Question with instance variables:

```
import Foundation

class QuestionModel {
 let question: String?
 let answers: [String]
}
```

I also have a class on parse.com (named Question) database with an object I created and I added three columns (a string name question, an array of strings named answers and a string named date of the question so that I can access it).

On my view controller I want to create an instance of the class Question with the data from the parse:

```
let newQuestion = QuestionModel()

var query = PFQuery(className:"Questions")
query.whereKey("date", equalTo:"5/17/15")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if error == nil {
    // The find succeeded.
    println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
    // Do something with the found objects
    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
      for object in objects {
        newQuestion.options = object["options"] as? [String]
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
  }

}

println(newQuestion.options)
```

It prints that it found 1 object
But when I add that last println, it prints nil. Why isn't it printing the question String I added on the Parse database?

Comment: That last printLn runs first, before the query even begins.  The code in the block param runs after the query is complete.  There's nothing to print until that block is running.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! But how can I make it so that the query and the block code run before i use the instance of the question?

Comment: use it only from within the block, or from some method that you call from the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asynch methods with completion blocks are tricky, because the code doesn't execute in the order you find it in the source file...

```
// edit - outside of this method, in the containing class:
var question: QuestionModel

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      self.question.options = // ...
      // use objects here, e.g. what your posted code does
      // update your UI with objects here, because they are valid here
      println("this runs SECOND")
      // no matter what you assign in here...
}

// ...it won't be accessible here, because this code runs *before* the code
// in the block
println("this runs FIRST")
```

Comment: Thanks, now I get it! But what can I do if I want to get data from Parse and use it outside this block i.e on an instance I create( the question, in this case) and use it throught my project? Does this mean that this is not the right method for me to use?

Comment: What I really want is to create an instance of the question class I created as I posted the code using the data I get from this method. What do you suggest? Thanks

Comment: I'd like to be more instructive, but I'm a dilettante in Swift.  The code you posted that builds newQuestion looks okay, but if you want it to last longer than the completion block, it should be assigned to a property of the class that contains the code we're discussing.  I assume that, ultimately, you'd like the user to see something of the result.  That too must be initiated from within the block.  Please see edit.